# Python Change JSON file without updating entire file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
def update_data(new_data):
    with open(data_container, "w") as file: # data_container is a string for the path
        json.dump(new_data, file)


def change_nation_data(key, key_data):
    data = get_data() # This just returns the file's old data
    data[key] = key_data
    update_data(data)
```

I have a rather large data file which will end up having tens if not hundreds of thousands of keys. The current version copies the entire file, changes just one key's value, then rewrites the entire file, and is naturally very slow. Is it possible to update just a single key in a json file without rewriting the entire file?

If not, is there a similar storage to json (arrays + dictionaries) that would allow me to do this?

Edit: Similarly, is it possible to only load a specific key?

Comment: It's only possible if your updated value is exactly the same size (that is, number of bytes) as the old value.

Comment: You could consider using a key-value DB : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database or a document DB : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database